# Linking lots of classes together

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns

Hm, I don't really know what title would be the best. So, I'm trying to implement a 'boolean circuit designer' (not homework, for learning purpose). I've started with a simple example: given an input port, output port, 2 wires, a power source, and relay. The circuit would look like:

- input port is connected to the 1st wire
- output port iis connected to the 2nd wire
- the other end of the second wire is connected to the power
- the 2 wires are connected in the middle with the relay

Looks like:

```
->in------------------------>
                         |
        power-----------relay----------out->
```

It simply negates the input bit. I'm implementing it in C++, so  want to make a good class hierarchy. 
As you see, inputs can be connected to wires, outputs to wires, wires to relays, and more variations. For this, I have an empty class `port`, and this is a base class of all wires, relays and so on. A sample code might look like this:

```
struct port {
    //nothing
};

struct power : public port {
    bool poweron = true;
};

struct relay : public port {
    port* input;
    bool on; //will depend on input wire's signal
};

struct wire : public port {
    port* input; //input end
    port* output; //output end
    std::vector<port*> outports; //output sockets for additional branching
    std::vector<port*> inports;  //input sockets for additional branching
};

struct bit_input : public port {
    port* output; //bit input can be vector too
};

struct bit_output : public port {
    port* input; //only one input bit to the bit output (lol)
};

int main(void)
{
    bit_input bin;
    bit_output bout;
    wire w0, w1;
    power p;
    relay r;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    bin.output = &w0; //input wire connected to boolean input's output:    ->bin------->
    bout.input = &w1;  //output wire connected to boolean output's input:         ------->bout->

    w1.input = &p; //output wire's input end is set to the power supply        power------->bout->
    w1.output = &bout; //output wire's output end is set to the boolean output

    w0.input = &bin; //input wire's input end is set to the boolean input's output

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    w0.outports.push_back(&r); //one of input wire's output port is set to the relay;     ->bin---|--->
                                                                                    //          relay
                                                                                    //     power--|---->bout->
    w1.inports.push_back(&r); //relay is connected to one of output wire's inut ports too

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    r.input = &w0; //relay's input bit is set to input wire

    return 0;
};
```

It's just a fast code, without interface for doing the connections. So, are there (certainly the are)  better ways of doing this kind of hierarchy, with lots of links to together. This was just an example, because it still doesn't handle signals, branching and so on...

The main problem is the use of pointers to link parts together, because for this I have to keep track of the types when dereferencing pointers. So I could use void pointers too for this... I tried to use directly pointers to these structs, but had to make templates e.g. `wire<power_supply, wire<whatever,whatever>>` for a wire input end can be connected to a power, out end to another wire. But wire is a template, so when I want to connect up to 1000 wires, this does not lead something good. I haven't found any good solutions in case of more than 2 classes which need to be referenced by eachother.

Comment: Though I don't really know/understand the problem domain, but it seems to me that you don't need to model the wires themselves. Every component has its pointers to other components connected to it, and by that pointer it could be able to get information from those connected components. For getting that information I would probably try to use polymorph/virtual functions which the connected component can call, thereby try to eliminate the need to know the exact type for dereferencing the pointer

Comment: the problem is like this with more classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493745/c-linking-2-classes-together-how. I don't know in advance which class will have a link to which class. The boolean circuit was an example, I've faced this problem earlier too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't really understand your question/problem completely, nor the problem domain. I'm guessing you don't really understand the concept of polymorphism. So to illustrate that concept here an example.

```
input ----|  
power---relay1----|  
power----------relay2----Lamp
```

Seeing this diagram now, its probably not the best, but its to illustrate the concept. So what I want to do here is use relay1 as input to relay2 which will make the lamp burn.. something like that

```
#include <iostream>

struct Component {
    virtual void calculate(){};
    bool state;
};

struct Relay : public Component {
    Component* input;
    Component* power;
    Component* output;

    void calculate() {
        bool inputOn = input->state;
        bool hasPower = power->state;
        if (inputOn && hasPower) {
            this->state = true;
        } else {
            this->state = false;
        }
        output->calculate();
    }
};

struct Lamp : public Component {
    Component* input;

    void calculate() {
        this->state = input->state;
    }
};

int main(){

    Component input;
    input.state = true;

    Component power;
    power.state = true;

    Lamp lamp;
    lamp.state = false;

    Relay relay1;
    Relay relay2;

    relay1.input = &input;
    relay1.power = &power;
    relay1.output = &relay2;
    relay1.state = false;

    relay2.input = &relay1;
    relay2.power = &power;
    relay2.output = &lamp;
    relay2.state = false;

    lamp.input = &relay2;
    lamp.state = false;

    relay1.calculate();

    std::cout << "Lamp state = " << lamp.state;

    return 0;
}
```

What I try to illustrate here is that the implementations of calculate in relay or lamp does not need to know about the specific type of the connected components to be able to calculate. Therefore you don't need to include them in their declaration/definition files or change code afterwards when you add new types of components.

This is a very rudimentary implementation, but I hope it helps.

Comment: that helped! I've just a bit overcomplicated the problem. That 'recursive' calculate function is nice.:)

Comment: This is basically a tree like structure, traversing it recursively is considered the more 'natural' way ;)   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Types